# How could I ignore bin and obj folders from git repository?

Tags: .net, git, gitignore

I want to ignore bin and obj folders from my git repository. As I've found out, there is no easy way to do this in .gitignore. So, are there any other way? Using clean solution in Visual Studio?

Comment: It works OK for me - I add the words 'bin' and 'obj' as separate lines in my .gitignore file

Comment: And if solution consists of many projects, not just one?

Comment: Can you post exactly what you are trying and what isn't working. `obj` and `bin` in a top level .gitignore should ignore everything called `obj` or `bin` at all lower levels.

Comment: My understanding is that the .gitignore contents apply in every subdirectory, so plain 'bin' and 'obj' work everywhere. Will post my .gitignore in an answer.

Answer (score 246, accepted):

I'm not sure why this doesn't work for you. In case it helps, here's a typical .gitignore file from one of my Visual Studio/git projects:

```
*.suo
*.user
_ReSharper.*
bin
obj
packages
```

Comment: I also add `packages` as you can easily re-download them from NuGet

Comment: it does not work when you first commit all files and then add .gitignore file to your repo and commit it. Newly ignored files are still will be shown as modified (if you rebuild, for example).

Comment: I recently used the suggested .gitignore file found here: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore with great success.

Comment: @BigTFromAZ You should add that as an answer, it's much better than the accepted one!

Answer (score 136):

simply making an entry in gitignore may not ignore files, you may need to commit it. I used the following method and worked for me

```
git rm -r --cached .

git add .
```

then

```
git commit -am "Remove ignored files"
```

However, this ignores my scripts folder which I included later into the repository.

Comment: It works OK. But Vscode couldn't find the modified code. I changed something myself and I pushed it to origin master. Then it worked. :)

Comment: I have a solution with many projects and for some reason the git add . never completes.

Comment: Great Arvind!, a newbie developer merged all bin/ and obj/ to our working branch (skiping policies ... i don't know how!) and this was the way for remove all those files from the repo.

Comment: Newbie me (at least to git), I did this to myself.  Never thought to rm and then add back because I didn't understand that git rm only deletes the items from the index and not the disk.  So if I understand correctly, your first two commands rebuilt the index by deleting everything from the index and adding everything back, applying the .gitignore filters. Then the commit makes it so in the repository.  Very clever.

Comment: Great! This worked perfectly well for me. all .vs, obj, bin and other ignored files.

Comment: This is a very under-rated answer. Thanks

Answer (score 37):

#### Update

After a recent update of Visual Studio 2019, the below option was not available.
Alternatively, you can also copy the latest gitignore content from the below location.
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github/gitignore/master/VisualStudio.gitignore

#### Original Answer

If you are using Visual Studio then there is a simple way to do this.

1. Open Team Explorer
2. Click on settings
3. Repository Settings
4. Under Ignore & Attribute file section
   Click on Add beside Ignore file.

It will create a default .gitignore file, which will ignore most of the common folders & files that will be used by the framework/language.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 15):

If you have committed the bin and obj folders previously, adding them to .gitignore will not automatically delete them.
You need to commit deleting these folders with for example 
`git rm -rf obj` or `git rm -rf yourProject/obj`
then commit the deletion

Answer (score 9):

I have had some new developers check in their OBJ and Bin files to the repository.
Even though I have the git ignore to exclude those files it would not work in my local repo.

I did the following to fix this

1. Deleted the Bin and Obj folders from the repository.
2. Deleted bin and obj folders from my local repo as well.
3. Created/Update the gitignore and save (If not done already)

If you have other user specific files also in the repo ex: .suo in  Visual studio
you can add them to the gitignore file after doing the above.

I found this after wasting quiet a bit of time hope this helps some one in the same scenario.

Answer (score 9):

Try adding the names of unwanted folders and git will never take those changes right from that root directory mentioned onward. This worked for me though to add these folder names into `.gitignore`:

```
bin
obj
packages
```

Answer (score 7):

- Locate the `bin` and `obj` folders in Windows Explorer
- Right click TortoiseGit > Delete and add to ignore list > bin
- Right click TortoiseGit > Delete and add to ignore list > obj

Answer (score 3):

If you want to ignore bin and obj in ALL your projects then you can use (from [gitignore man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore))

> Patterns read from the file specified by the configuration variable core.excludesfile.

core.excludesfile can be set in a config file which is ~/.gitconfig in Unix - I don't know where it is under Windows

Comment: Good info, but he meant all his Visual Studio projects in this solution not ALL projects on the machine.

Comment: Although most likely he'll never be interested in commiting the `bin` and `obj` folders in ANY solution. :)

Answer (score 3):

@Raphael Pinel is absolutely correct.  .gitignore doesn't work if the files are already in the Git repository.

I'm using VS2019 and Azure DevOps as my Git repository.  Here's how I fixed it.

In Visual Studio, add .gitignore file (if necessary) and push that file to the repository.

```
 Team Explorer->Changes->Right Click
 .gitignore->Stage.
```

Then commit staged, then sync.
Go to Azure DevOps website.
Delete bin/obj folders from Git repository.
In Visual Studio,

```
Team Explorer->Changes->"Undo Changes" to those folders.
Team Explorer->Synch->Pull to update local Git repository.
```

You can now build your project and Git will ignore the folders as specified in the .gitignore file.

Answer (score 0):

If you try through source tree and still the ignore files are not coming in ,   go to  tools-->option->Git and then select location of  the .gitignore
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, bin and obj folders were nested under Project folder from the root .gitignore file, so I had to add it like below:

[PROJECT_FOLDER_NAME]/bin
[PROJECT_FOLDER_NAME]/obj

Replace PROJECT_FOLDER_NAME with your project folder name