# How to clean an ASP.NET MVC project of all build artifacts to send to git repository?

Tags: c#, asp.net, git, visual-studio

I have created a simple ASP.NET MVC web app in Visual Studio 2017.

The project directory contains a lot of build artifacts, and I'd like to minimize it so that it has only the source code and other essential files.

If this is not possible, which directories should I delete? My guess is that `obj` and `bin` directories are safe to go.

Comment: Those directories will be generated every build. Those files need to exist to make the application run. I think the approach you're looking for is to save only code to a repository.

Comment: @IamDOM I need to push the code to github, as well as get a zip of the directory. I thought there should be an command to remove the artifacts, as other build tools I am used to do provide them, like `mvn clean`.

In case using gitignore is the only solution, which folders should I add to it?

Comment: Please check my answer.

Comment: FYI - There is a [**VisualStudio.gitignore**](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore) file that is kept up to date with all of the latest "garbage" files that Visual Studio and common extensions create, so you can avoid committing any of them.

Comment: @NightOwl888 I ended up using that file in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to remove those files / folders locally, you only need to tell Git you don't want to keep them on your repository.

You can achieve that by creating a .gitignore file inside your repository folder. This file lets you specify which folders or files you want to be removed from your repository.

From the docs:

> From time to time, there are files you don't want Git to check in to GitHub. There are a few ways to tell Git which files to ignore.

**Navigate to the location of your Git repository and create a .gitignore file with the extensions, files or folders you want to ignore.**

Here are some of common extension / folders you want to ignore in a VS project:

```
*.suo
*.user
_ReSharper.*
bin
obj
packages
```

Sources:

https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2347375/6490459