# How to ignore folder bin obj .vs in visual studio 2019

Tags: git, ignore

How to ignore folder bin, obj and .vs in visual studio 2019?

[image]

Comment: Add it to `.gitignore` file if you want to it skip during commit

Comment: .gitignore not work!?

Comment: whats command is  for .gitignore?

Comment: https://help.github.com/en/articles/ignoring-files

Comment: What did you put in your .gitignore file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How could I ignore bin and obj folders from git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347335/how-could-i-ignore-bin-and-obj-folders-from-git-repository)

Answer (score 4):

Use https://gitignore.io/ and enter 'VisualStudio' (and perhaps also the technology you are using) and it will generate a good '.gitignore' file that you could commit.

Comment: ignore folder bin in visual studio 2019

Comment: @HatefHatefi What do you mean? Read the linked docs, consider using Philippe's suggested tool to generate a first draft of it. If something is unclear here, you'll have to be more specific.

Comment: So im having the same issue even though im using the generated visual studio gitignore file from the site linked above. @RomainValeri So Im not sure if this is an issue with visual studio itself or what. This same gitignore file works on many other solutions I work on but its not picking it up for this solution where the problem exists.

Comment: @CameronBelt Don't forget that already tracked files can't be ignored. You have to untrack the files already commited that you want to ignore.

Comment: I ended up creating a new repo in Azure Dev Ops and this time it asked me what IDE i wanted to generate the gitignore file for, and I selected Visual Studio. Its not an ideal solution but i needed to get past the problem and this ultimately worked.