# Git doesn't ignore obj and bin folders

Tags: git

I have following gitignore

```
**/node_modules
**/environment.ts
```

I tried for obj and bin the following

```
**/bin
*/bin
bin
/bin
bin/*
```

The structure of the folder is a main folder and I have 5 projects inside from which node_modules get ignored everywhere in the client project but for the netcore projects obj and bin doesn't get ignored and it drives me insane already.

I did `git rm -r . --cached` and all projects are unstaged right now, I wanna `git add Project1` and so on and push each one to a branch, but apparently bin and obj doesn't get ignored no matter what I am trying, those folders are added everytime

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How could I ignore bin and obj folders from git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347335/how-could-i-ignore-bin-and-obj-folders-from-git-repository)

Comment: nope, I tried all the answers, node_modules is ignored everywhere and I don't know what I am doing wrong. I basically have all 5 projects at the stage of Untracked files and I keep changing .gitignore, saving it and when I add it still adds the bin and obj

Comment: I can remove them manually tho and they stay untracked but those projects have additional class library projects and I don't wanna remove manually like 20 paths

Comment: It is also possible to have additional .gitignore files in subdirectories / *sub-projects*. These only apply to files or folders within that directory.

Comment: I will try right now

Comment: Ok *I think* its because I created .gitignore with notepad.. I created a new gitignore in Project 2 with touch .gitignore, I added the names without anything and magically they are ignored. I try again to replicate in the main folder maybe I can get away with one .gitignore if not I will go with one .gitignore for each project.

Comment: Great. Let us know how it goes.

Comment: Sounds like an encoding issue - maybe Notepad creates the file with `UTF-16` or something else that is not supported by git.

Comment: What are your autocrlf settings and contents of .gitattributes file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can try and setup a file in your $HOME with the same exclude rules, and

```
git config --global core.excludesFile /path/to/file
```

That way, it would apply to *all* Git repositories.

Check if your non-ignored folders are in paths referenced by a `.gitmodules` (ie are in submodules), or in paths with a `.git/` nested repository in them.
That would mean the root `.gitignore` would not be applied to those subrepos.

---

> Ok I think its because I created .gitignore with notepad.

That would make a .gitignore with CRLF eol (end of line characters), instead of LF, which could explain why the rules are not properly applied.

A `dos2unix` (packaged with Git for Windows in `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\dos2unix.exe`) would be enough to fix this.